# MAC: missing: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR && OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: macos, opengl, cmake, zlib

Zlib is supposed to be installed on all mac's by default I'm pretty sure.. But when I run cmake for SFML I get the following errors:

```
The C compiler identification is Clang 4.1.0
The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.1.0
Check for working C compiler using: Xcode
Check for working C compiler using: Xcode -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode
Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
Found Freetype: /usr/X11R6/lib/libfreetype.dylib (found version "2.4.4")
Found GLEW: /Users/falconmick/Documents/SFML2 src/extlibs/libs-osx/lib/libGLEW.a
Found JPEG: /Users/falconmick/Documents/SFML2 src/extlibs/libs-osx/lib/libjpeg.a
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:85 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt:85 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
used as include directory in directory /Users/falconmick/Documents/SFML2 src/src/SFML/Window

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Help CMake to locate it by setting `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` variable. Either run this:

```
cmake -D ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/zlib/include .
```

in your build directory, or set it via GUI.

Comment: Not too sure if this would work with this project in particular, but I've done more cmake work and this does look like something I would do now I have more experience..

Hope anyone else with this issue finds this useful